# Making an image appear in background when hovering over a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

Basically what I am trying to do is make an image appear behind a link when I hover over it.

This is my CSS so far:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

#css-zen-garden {
background-image: url(images/batswarm.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #535353
}

#container{
margin: 10%;
background-color: silver;
border: white solid 3px;
padding: 5px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
color: white;
}

a:hover {
background-image: url(images/batman-logo.gif);
color: #535353;
}

header ~ div, article > div {
border-bottom: 3px dotted #535353
}

::selection {
background-color: red;
}
```

on my    a:hover, I want that image to appear in the background of the link, not below it. Any help on this would be very much appreciated. My html code is at the bottom too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>css Zen Garden: The Beauty in CSS Design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="zenstyle.css" />

</head>
<body id="css-zen-garden">

<div id="container">
<div id="intro">
<!--  -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - -    HEADER  - - - - - - - - -   -->
<header>
<div id="pageHeader">
<h1><span>css Zen Garden</span></h1>
<h2><span>The Beauty of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Design</span></h2>
</div>
</header>

<!-- - - - - - - - - -    QUICK SUMMARY   - - - - - - - - -   -->
<div id="quickSummary">
<article>
<p class="p1"><span>A demonstration of what can be accomplished visually through <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>-based design. Select any style sheet from the list to load it into this page.</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span>Download the sample <a href="#" title="This page's source HTML code, not to be modified.">html file</a> and <a href="#" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify.">css file</a></span></p>
</article>
</div>

<!-- - - - - - - - - -    PREAMBLE  - - - - - - - - -   -->     
<div id="preamble">
<article>
<h3><span>The Road to Enlightenment</span></h3>
<p class="p1"><span>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, and broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support.</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span>Today, we must clear the mind of past practices. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>, <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr> and the major browser creators.</span></p>
<p class="p3"><span>The css Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the (yet to be) time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</span></p>
</article>
</div>
</div>

<!-- - - - - - - - - -    SUPPORTING TEXT    - - - - - - - - -   -->
<div id="supportingText">
<article>
<div id="explanation">
<h3><span>So What is This About?</span></h3>
<p class="p1"><span>There is clearly a need for <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> to be taken seriously by graphic artists. The Zen Garden aims to excite, inspire, and encourage participation. To begin, view some of the existing designs in the list. Clicking on any one will load the style sheet into this very page. The code remains the same, the only thing that has changed is the external .css file. Yes, really.</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> allows complete and total control over the style of a hypertext document. The only way this can be illustrated in a way that gets people excited is by demonstrating what it can truly be, once the reins are placed in the hands of those able to create beauty from structure. To date, most examples of neat tricks and hacks have been demonstrated by structurists and coders. Designers have yet to make their mark. This needs to change.</span></p>
</div>

<!-- - - - - - - - - -    PARTICIPATION    - - - - - - - - -   -->      
<div id="participation">
<h3><span>Participation</span></h3>
<p class="p1"><span>Graphic artists only please. You are modifying this page, so strong <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> skills are necessary, but the example files are commented well enough that even <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> novices can use them as starting points. Please see the <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/resources/" title="A listing of CSS-related resources"><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Resource Guide</a> for advanced tutorials and tips on working with <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>.</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span>You may modify the style sheet in any way you wish, but not the <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr>. This may seem daunting at first if you&#8217;ve never worked this way before, but follow the listed links to learn more, and use the sample files as a guide.</span></p>
<p class="p3"><span>Download the sample <a href="#" title="This page's source HTML code, not to be modified.">html file</a> and <a href="#" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify.">css file</a> to work on a copy locally. Once you have completed your masterpiece (and please, don&#8217;t submit half-finished work) upload your .css file to a web server under your control. <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/submit/" title="Use the contact form to send us your CSS file">Send us a link</a> to the file and if we choose to use it, we will spider the associated images. Final submissions will be placed on our server.</span></p>
</div>

<!-- - - - - - - - - -    BENEFITS  - - - - - - - - -   -->                 
<div id="benefits">
<h3><span>Benefits</span></h3>
<p class="p1"><span>Why participate? For recognition, inspiration, and a resource we can all refer to when making the case for <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>-based design. This is sorely needed, even today. More and more major sites are taking the leap, but not enough have. One day this gallery will be a historical curiosity; that day is not today.</span></p>
</div>

<!-- - - - - - - - - -    REQUIREMENTS  - - - - - - - - -   -->     
<div id="requirements">
<h3><span>Requirements</span></h3>
<p class="p1"><span>We would like to see as much <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets, version 1">CSS1</abbr> as possible. <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets, version 2">CSS2</abbr> should be limited to widely-supported elements only. The css Zen Garden is about functional, practical <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> and not the latest bleeding-edge tricks viewable by 2% of the browsing public. The only real requirement we have is that your <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> validates.</span></p>
<p class="p2"><span>Unfortunately, designing this way highlights the flaws in the various implementations of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>. Different browsers display differently, even completely valid <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> at times, and this becomes maddening when a fix for one leads to breakage in another. View the <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/resources/" title="A listing of CSS-related resources">Resources</a> page for information on some of the fixes available. Full browser compliance is still sometimes a pipe dream, and we do not expect you to come up with pixel-perfect code across every platform. But do test in as many as you can. If your design doesn&#8217;t work in at least IE5+/Win and Mozilla (run by over 90% of the population), chances are we won&#8217;t accept it.</span></p>
<p class="p3"><span>We ask that you submit original artwork. Please respect copyright laws. Please keep objectionable material to a minimum; tasteful nudity is acceptable, outright pornography will be rejected.</span></p>
<p class="p4"><span>This is a learning exercise as well as a demonstration. You retain full copyright on your graphics (with limited exceptions, see <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/submit/guidelines/">submission guidelines</a>), but we ask you release your <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> under a Creative Commons license identical to the <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/1.0/" title="View the Zen Garden's license information.">one on this site</a> so that others may learn from your work.</span></p>

</div>


</article>
</div>





</div>

<!-- These extra divs/spans may be used as catch-alls to add extra imagery. -->
<div id="extraDiv1"><span></span></div>
<div id="extraDiv2"><span></span></div>
<div id="extraDiv3"><span></span></div>
<div id="extraDiv4"><span></span></div>
<div id="extraDiv5"><span></span></div>
<div id="extraDiv6"><span></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's too many details missing from your question to give a specific answer.  Based on your CSS, the image *should* show as part of the background of the a element, however, there's questions: (a) How big is the link? (b) What content is in the link? (c) Is the link display: block? (d) Does the image have padding, white space, etc. that pushes it down?

Comment: The link is small, only two words, saying "html link". This link downloads a sample html page. No the link does not display: block;. Nothing else surrounds the link. If you need the html I can put it up. Also my picture is pretty big, so I probably have to edit it and make it small enough to fit the tiny link space.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code too?

Comment: I am trying to put the background image for the batman-logo.gif for all the links in the html.

Comment: Does the color change when you hover?

Comment: The image has a white background and the black batman symbol in the middle of it. The white shows up when I hover, and that's why I think the image may be too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you trying to load the image isn't working. I tried copying and pasting in the code and trying to use my own image, and this code worked fine:

```
a:hover {
background-image:url(batman-logo.gif);
color: #535353;
}
```

I did this (with an image not called batman-logo.gif, though) and it worked absolutely fine. I'm guessing something is wrong with your path to the image.

Comment: If not, it might be the image is too big, in which case, try this: http://seeclickfix.com/files/user_images/0000/1525/Batman_logo_small_square.jpg